# Proof validity of formulas or disproof by counterexample

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Given a relation symbol $A$. Then I want to show or find a counterexample for the validity of the following formulas:

- $(\forall a \exists b A(a,b)) \to (\exists b \forall a A(a,b))$
- $\Bigl[\forall a \forall b \forall c \Bigl( \left(A(a,b) \land A(b,c)\right) \to A(a,c) \Bigr)\Bigr] \land \Bigl[\forall a \exists b A(a,b)\Bigr] \to \exists a A(a,a)$

The first one is false and as a counterexample I can look at $((0,1), \leq)$ where $R$ is $\leq$ then clearly $\forall a \exists b a \leq b$ namely $b = a$. By contraposition one can show that there is no $b \in (0,1)$ such that for all $a \in (0,1)$ we have $a \leq b$.
Also for the second one we can construct a infinite chain $R(x,y),R(y,z),R(x,z), \ldots$ such that one cannot gurantee that there exists an $x$ such that $R(x,x)$.
I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: For the 2nd assertion, try $$[A(a,b)] \iff [a < b]. $$  That is, think *transitive*, but not *reflexive*.

Comment: I would suggest (if you want to stay as formal in logic as possible) to use the Ideas for Validity in Margaris "First order Mathematical Logic" on pp28 ff.
Or you try the model theoretic approach from Robbin "Mathematical Logic: A first course" Technically they are the same (but Margaris approach is somewhat clearer)